# TYPO3: subpages menu: filter by category?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

in TYPO3 there is a content element: a menu that displays subpages. Now I want to have some kind of filter function: the user should be able to select a TYPO3 system category and then the menu should only display subpages that belong to this category.

Is there an extension that I can use for a lookup or as a base to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

There is a content element type "Categorized Pages" that does exactly that.

If you need it to react to a user input coming form the frontend, you can easily add some lines of TypoScript to modify the rendering of that element so that it will consume a GET parameter to configure itself.